# SQL WHERE IN Multiple subqueries

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE 
 WHERE ID IN (subquery1) 
    OR ID IN (subquery2)
```

Only returning results that are included in subquery 2.

How can I get results that are included in both subqueries?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, but maybe XOR?

Comment: You can't be running this on MySQL -and- SQL Server -and- PostgreSQL???  ***Which*** one are you actually using?  *(As a debugging exercise, please show examples of what each subquery returns.)*

Comment: Please try this example ( https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f052f08bb54685c2a9257d3f584176b0 ), then modify it to demonstrate when you problem behaviour occurs *(editing the question to include the link to your modified example)*.  I can't replicate your problem on any of those databases, this implies you have a bug in subquery1.

Comment: I have removed all the conflicting RDBMS. Please tag the RDBMS you are *really* using and **only** that RDBMS. Tag spamming doesn't help anyone help you, it just makes your question more confusing and can attract downvotes (as it appears to have done here).

Answer (score 0):

If you want both, then use `AND`:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM TABLE T
WHERE T.ID IN (subquery1) AND
      T.ID IN (subquery2);
```

Comment: It doesn't return correct results. It returns the common between both

Comment: Ummm, I think the the OP is saying that they want id's that appear in subquery1 even if they don't appear in subquery2 *(and vice versa)*?  But, at present, they only get the ids that appear in subquery2?

Comment: @MohamadKassar If `AND` show what's common then `OR` shows the union of both. Are you sure that ALL what's in subquery1 isn't  in subquery2, or do you want a row for subquery1 and another for subquery2 ?

Comment: @MohamadKassar check with `subquery1 except subquery2`

Comment: @MohamadKassar . . . The question is:  "How can I get results that are included in both subqueries?".